# What is the best way to get Facebook retrieve data of a url (like count, comment count, share count ...)?

Tags: javascript, api, sdk, facebook-opengraph

What is the best way to get #Facebook retrieve data of a url (like count, comment count, share count ...) #OpenGraph #API #Javascript #SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=YOUR_URL&access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```